# What arguments do dispensationalists have in favour of the views of Anderson and Hoehner concerning the 69 weeks in Daniel 9:24-27?

Tags: dispensationalism, prophecy

Today is Palm Sunday, when our Lord made his Triumphal Entry into Jerusalem seated on a humble donkey. Both Robert Anderson, in his book The Coming Prince (1894), and Harold Hoehner, in Chronological Aspects of the Life of Christ (1978) argue that 69 of the 70 weeks in Daniel 9:24-27 ends with the Triumphal Entry on Palm Sunday.

Anderson claims the starting date for the 69 weeks was 14th March 445 BC which he derives from Nehemiah 2:1. He assumed it was on the 1st of Nisan that Artaxerxes I gave a decree to Nehemiah to go to Jerusalem to rebuild it. Anderson also claims that the Triumphal Entry happened on 6th April AD 32. By using a 360 day "prophetic year" Anderson then claimed the period in question is 483 years (69 weeks) to the exact day.

Hoehner felt Anderson's date range was untenable, probably because in AD 32 the 14th Nisan, the day the Passover lambs were slain, was on a Monday, impossible to reconcile with a Sunday resurrection. He therefore argued that the 20th year of Artaxerxes I (Nehemiah 2:1) was a year later and placed the start of the 69 weeks as 5th March 444 BC. He then claimed the Triumphal Entry happened on 30th March AD 33. He also kept Anderson's 360 day "prophetic year". He also claimed the period is 483 years, 69 weeks, to the exact day.

My question is "**What arguments do dispensationalists have in favour of these theories?**"

I'm assuming Anderson's theory is more or less replaced by Hoehner's, since AD 32 for the crucifixion is a non-starter. But arguments in favour of either are welcome.

(I have asked a parallel question: What arguments do non-dispensationalists have against the theories of Anderson and Hoehner concerning the 69 weeks of Daniel 9:24-27?)

Comment: The only thing that makes Monday, April 14, 32 AD difficult for some to accept is the assumption that Mary discovered Jesus on the very same morning as the resurrection. The 32 AD calendar would necessitate that the resurrection occurred on Thursday evening - the night before "preparation day" (Friday) for the second Sabbath of the week - Saturday. There is nothing in scripture that disallows Jesus from being discovered two days following the resurrection. In fact, it is completely logical flow because they would not have wanted to be in contact with a "corpse" until after the second Sabbath.